# How to pass Dynamic Range string text to SQL query IN clause in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the Dynamic Range String data, need to pass trim the cell and single quote and comma separated to SQL query.

```
A
123ABC345
234CDE678
ZSE123MTR
POR123456
```

Result:

```
select * from table name where col1 in ('123ABC345','234CDE678','ZSE123MTR','POR123456')
```

Comment: I need this in Excel VBA, Range is not static, it's dynamic data.

Comment: I didn't say you don't need VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim query as String

query = "select * from table name where col1 in ("

range("A1").Select

While ActiveCell.Value <> "" and ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""

query = query + "'" + Activecell.Value + "', "

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Wend

query = query + "'" + Activecell.Value + "')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
sqlstr = "select * from table name where col1 in ('"
sqlstr = sqlstr & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A4").Value), "','") & "')"
```